# How can one map the role name in Authorize attribute

Tags: c#, security, asp.net-mvc-3

I could use a good idea to "map" the role string in the [Authorize] attribute:

Have:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "SecAdmin")]    
public class UserAccessController : Controller
```

Would like something like:

```
[Authorize(Roles = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SecAdminRole"] )]    
public class UserAccessController : Controller
```

So that I can switch between test and production AD roles, or should i just create a custom Authorize attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The custom Authorize attribute seems the best deal here.

You could also put the test/production separation somewhere else in your project. For example, write a custom role provider for test mode, which will grant the test admins the 'Admin' role.

Comment: Hi Zruty, I actually already have a custom role provider, that have worked nicely in development. I have implemented my custom Authorize attribute and it works fine.